# Angular Build Error: If it was intentional, convert the expression to "unknown" first angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've the following code, which works fine locally...

[image: 1]

...but once I try to build the application, the following error message appears:

[image: 2]

Comment: return {...item.payload.doc, id:item.prop1.prop2.id} try something like this

Comment: It seems like you're *casting* your `object` to [**Event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)...